# Hidden Menu activate Main Menu Active States, How?

Tags: active

I've ask this question on Joomla Official Forums-http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=862922&f=706

### But no one is able to help.

I need some help, I'm new to Joomla, I've created a website for my friend- http://www.maverikswarehouse.com I'm stuck on the menus active states I'm using FavouriteDark theme

I've created a Hidden Menu, these have category blogs in them, how do I make the Main Menu items in active state while one of the posts in hidden menu is clicked?

For example- I click on Gallery, then i click on one of the items, it will redirect to an article post, but the Gallery Menu is no longer active. How do I make it active?

Thanks

Kenwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a few tricks you can try.

1. If you don't want to display submenu items (children) in main menu, you could add the menu items of your hidden menu as child menu items of the associated parent item of the main menu. Then go in the menu module for the main menu and set it to not display submenu items, or render only 1st level menu items.
2. Another approach that I have also seen working is this:

   a. Rename the alias of the current menu item for the blog (e.g. from blog to blog-temp).

   b. In your hidden menu, create 1 Parent menu item for the blog and give it the name you desired. (e.g. blog).

   c. Then put the rest of the menu items for your blog categories as children of the above.

   d. Go back to the initial blog menu item and change its type, to a **System Link Type -> Menu Item Alias**, set it to be alias of the new Blog Menu Item you created on the hidden menu.

Now, all the rest menu items for the blog categories should be children of the Parent menu item for the Blog, which usually adds the "active" class to the current menu item and its parent (on the core menu module).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help :), I'll try all the solutions tmr, Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla cannot infer the relationship between a hidden menu a different menu item in the frontpage.

I would write a Javascript to define the relationship, for instance if browser has this URL, activate this menu item.